# Using an array inside "GetElementbyID"

Tags: javascript

I have used the following code to enter variable text into fields but was wondering could I use an array instead:

```js
document.getElementById("PLG").innerHTML = PLGame;
document.getElementById("PLV").innerHTML = PLV;
document.getElementById("PLKOT").innerHTML = PLKOT;
document.getElementById("PLS1").innerHTML = PLS1;
document.getElementById("PLS2").innerHTML = PLS2;
document.getElementById("PLS3").innerHTML = PLS3;
document.getElementById("PLPred").innerHTML = PLPred;
```

I assume it would be along the lines of:

```js
for (i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
let myArray = ["PLG","PLV","PLKOT","PLS1","PLS2","PLS3","PLPred"];
let outArray = ["PLGame","PLV","PLKOT","PLS1","PLS2","PLS3","PLPred"];     
document.getElementById("myArray[i]").innerHTML = OutArray[i];
```

I imagine there's a lot wrong with that but I'm still learning JS so go easy on me :)

Comment: Try`document.getElementById(myArray[i]).innerHTML = OutArray[i];`

Comment: Instead of doing index based matching, it's much easier and more reliable to use an object for the purpose. `const obj = { "PLG": "PLGame", "PLV": "PLV", ...}` and then iterate over the properties of this object using `for (const id in obj) document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = obj[id];`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237316/discussion-on-question-by-steve-hartley-using-an-array-inside-getelementbyid).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to javascript, Steve!

We can use a for loop to achieve this:

```
// Let's begin by comma-separating the two "let" statements into one.
let myArray = ["PLG","PLV","PLKOT","PLS1","PLS2","PLS3","PLPred"],
    outArray = ["PLGame","PLV","PLKOT","PLS1","PLS2","PLS3","PLPred"];

// Then we'll use myArray inside a for loop, to call values from outArray.
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(myArray[i]).innerHTML = outArray[i];
}
```

Note for new players - be careful with case-sensitivity in line 3 of your code. ( outArray vs OutArray )

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely multiple ways to do this. Following along with your current logic, you can create a `for` loop that will provide the index you need to index into both arrays and do the assignment.

I think a slightly better implementation is creating a single array with objects. That way, you don't have to worry about both arrays having the correct id/value pair at the exact same index.

```js
// method 1
const ids = ["PLG", "PLV", "PLKOT"]
const values = ["v1", "v2", "v3"]

for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(ids[i]).innerHTML = values[i]
}

// method 2
const pairs = [
  {
    id: 'PLG',
    value: 'v1'
  },
  {
    id: 'PLV',
    value: 'v2'
  },
  {
    id: 'PLKOT',
    value: 'v3'
  }
]

pairs.forEach((pair) => {
  document.getElementById(pair.id).innerHTML = pair.value
})
```

```html
<h1>Method 1</h1>

<div id="PLG"></div>
<div id="PLV"></div>
<div id="PLKOT"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the quotation mark from getElementById(). When you use quotation its taking it as a string not a variable.

```
document.getElementById(myArray[i]).innerHTML = OutArray[i];
```

Comment: Thanks both but the following code doesn't seem to work:

        ```const ids = ["PLG", "PLV", "PLKOT","PLS1","PLS2","PLS3","PLPred"];```
        ```const values = ["PLGame","PLV","PLKOT","PLS1","PLS2","PLS3","PLPred"];```

       ``` for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById(ids[i]).innerHTML = values[i];```